# Unable to install RabbitMQ using puppet due to curl error

Tags: curl, debian, rabbitmq, puppet

After having to downgrade the apt module of puppet to version 1.8.0 to clear some other errors I am not getting the current error:

```
==> dev_debian_dev: Error: curl -k --noproxy localhost --retry 30 --retry-delay 6 -f -L -o /var/lib/rabbitmq/rabbitmqadmin http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/cli/rabbitmqadmin returned 7 instead of one of [0]
==> dev_debian_dev: Error: /Stage[main]/Rabbitmq::Install::Rabbitmqadmin/Staging::File[rabbitmqadmin]/Exec[/var/lib/rabbitmq/rabbitmqadmin]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: curl -k --noproxy localhost --retry 30 --retry-delay 6 -f -L -o /var/lib/rabbitmq/rabbitmqadmin http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/cli/rabbitmqadmin returned 7 instead of one of [0]
==> dev_debian_dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Rabbitmq::Install::Rabbitmqadmin/File[/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin]: Dependency Exec[/var/lib/rabbitmq/rabbitmqadmin] has failures: true
```

The current module version is puppetlabs-rabbitmq (v5.2.1).

What do I have to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

something you need work out in your environment and fix the proxy issue.

```
CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)

Failed to connect() to host or proxy.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case... to enable connection to the rabbitmqadmin I've enabled the plugin manually:

```
$ rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
$ /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server restart
```

One valid workaround could be launch these commands from your puppet master.